# Ubuntu reinstall dhcp3-client

Tags: ubuntu, dhcp

Following advice from another SU question [(link)](https://superuser.com/questions/30878/ubuntu-static-ip-alias-dhcp-router-independent) I apt-get remove'd `dchp3-client` from a virtual machine on my computer. The problem the question was hoping to solve did not get resolved, and now I'm left with a VM that has no network access.

I'm relatively new to Ubuntu, and I'm not sure how to reinstall `dhcp3-client` without network access.  I have a host VM with Internet access as well as an 8GB USB drive.

What's the simplest way to get networking back on my VM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, as you are using VMs, you should abuse your ability to work on snapshots ... that would save you that kind of trouble.

To reinstall dhcp3-client, you just need to install it from the package

```
dhcp3-client_3.1.1-5ubuntu8.1_amd64.deb
```

This package might still be in your VM (look in /var/cache/apt/archives/), if not, transfer it into your VM after getting it [here](http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/d/dhcp3/dhcp3-client_3.1.1-5ubuntu8.1_amd64.deb) (if you don't know how to do so, you need to tell which virtualization software you use).

Then execute the following command in the directory containing the .deb:

```
sudo dpkg -i dhcp3-client_3.1.1-5ubuntu8.1_amd64.deb
```

(I assumed from the linked question that you are using Ubuntu 9.04 64bits on your VMs)

Comment: You're correct on your assumptions about 9.04 x64. I'm busy until later in the day - I'll try this out then.  I think I should be able to get the package into my VM, but if not, I'm using VMWare Workstation.  Thanks for the reply!